# Access URL from Oracle 11g

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle11g

I have a .NET Webform that accepts parameters through the URL and I need to call it from a trigger on our Oracle 11g database.
Basically, whenever the stock of a product changes, the trigger should call the URL with the information from the table like this:

```
'http://localhost:9999/Webform.aspx?ID=' || ID || '&quantity=' || quantity
```

There's no need for getting a response since the .NET webform will handle the rest.

I tried to do this:

```
begin
  dbms_network_acl_admin.create_acl (
  acl          => 'utl_http.xml',
  description  => 'my acl',
  principal    => 'user',
  is_grant     => TRUE,
  privilege    => 'connect',
  start_date   => null,  
  end_date     => null);
 commit;
 end;

begin
  dbms_network_acl_admin.add_privilege (
  acl         => 'utl_http.xml',
  principal   => 'user',
  is_grant    => false,
  privilege   => 'connect',
  position    => null,
  start_date  => null,
  end_date    => null);
 commit;
end;

declare
  req UTL_HTTP.REQ;
begin
  req := UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST('http://localhost:9999/Webform.aspx');
END;
```

But I got this from the first two:

```
anonymous block completed
```

And this from the third one:

```
ORA-29273: HTTP request failed 
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1130
ORA-12541: TNS:no listener 
ORA-06512: at line 7
29273. 00000 -  "HTTP request failed"
*Cause:    The UTL_HTTP package failed to execute the HTTP request.
*Action:   Use get_detailed_sqlerrm to check the detailed error message.
           Fix the error and retry the HTTP request.
```

Answer (score 0):

The **ORA-12541: TNS:no listener** jumps out at me in that error message. Assuming you're getting that feedback from your .NET IDE, then it may be possible your development database listener went down, while the database itself (for example if you used SQL*Plus on the database server) was still up.

On the database server, check the following command:
lsnrctl status